# rails update profile without knowing password

Tags: ruby-on-rails

using rails 3.2.8, I have an application where users can sign in and out, and modify their profile. I am using has_secure_password.

However, there is a requirement for an admin to be able to change some parts of their profile. Obviously, the admin does not know the users password.

How can I save the modified user profile without changing the password ? Only an admin has this functionality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this. What I ended up doing was to set the password and confirmation to a certain value (a guid) when displaying the form. When saving, the controller removes the fields from the params if they match that guid. The model then only validates (and saves) the password_digest if the fields are present

Answer (score 0):

Try using 'ActiveAdmin'.

Here's a Railscast explaining the details http://railscasts.com/episodes/284-active-admin

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have created current_user method.

users_controller

```
before_filter :authorize!, only: [:edit, :update]

def edit

end

def update

end

private
def authorize!
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to root_url(status: :unauthorized) unless current_user && (current_user.eql?(@user) || current_user.role.eql?("admin"))
end
```

Comment: Can't you just do something like current_user.admin?

Comment: I see now what you're doing. It depends on how it is architected.

Comment: thanks for the help, but I wasn't trying to check if a user was authorised to modify the record. I was trying to figure out how to "save" another user's record without knowing their password, as it is obviously hashed and therefore plain text not available. The password and confirmation are on the update form and are validated by the model, so I can't just leave them out.